# AngularJS : Trigger $watch in directive when a different element changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

I have two inputs (`field1`, `field2`) on a form. `field1` has a directive with a `$watch`, while `field2` has a `$watch` in a controller. `field1` displays "This has a value" or "This field has no value" after a value is added or added/removed. The message is blank when the input is pristine.

Changing `field2` changes the value of `field1` to blank. What I would like to happen is for "This field has no value" to be displayed for `field1` by triggering the `$watch` in the directive.

My project actually has more complex calculations and checks across multiple inputs, but this is the basic gist of what I need to do.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XMdDt8M34VZJw1W0hkDt?p=preview

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <p>
    <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
    <input custom-validator name="field1" ng-model="item.field1" type="text" />
    <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
    <input name="field2" ng-model="item.field2" type="text" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('customValidator', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
          if (value) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(ngModelCtrl.$name, false);
            scope.$parent.errorMessage = 'This field has a value.'
          } else {
            ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(ngModelCtrl.$name, true);
            scope.$parent.errorMessage = 'This field has no value.'
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    field1: '',
    field2: ''
  };

  $scope.$watch('item.field2', function(oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      $scope.item.field1 = '';
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add function to `$formatters` pipiline (because your are changing model from controller, not from view - then `$parsers` work) and run it if model is dirty:

```
myApp.directive('customValidator', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(ngModelCtrl.$name, false);
                    scope.errorMessage = 'This field has a value.'
                } else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(ngModelCtrl.$name, true);
                    scope.errorMessage = 'This field has no value.'
                }
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                if (!value && ngModelCtrl.$dirty) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(ngModelCtrl.$name, true);
                    scope.errorMessage = 'This field has no value.'
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I also made few additional corrections. First of all, removed `$parent` because your directive shares the same scope with error message. Then I changed order of parameters in `$watch` function: it's `newValue` first and the second is `oldValue`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/VXpsrhvYliW9ICtFsdY6?p=preview

Comment: How would you change this so that $parsers and $formatters use the same validation function? I'd like to avoid duplicating code.